# jQuery When().Done() not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making some ajax calls and I expect some or all of them to 404. The problem is that when I get a expected 404, the `.done()` is not executed! What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
$.each(data, function (index, item) {
    promises.push(GetReservation(item.UniqueId,
        apiRoot,
        function (data2) {
            //DO stuff
        },
        function (x, y, z) {
            if (x.status == 404) {
                //OK!!! i expected that!
            }
        }));
})
$.when.apply($, promises).done(function () {
    setButtons(box, c)
});
```

Comment: I promise you that when you have more than one promise, you have promises.

Comment: ok thank you... i will correct that in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $.when returns promise, you can call **always** instead of **done**. It will invoke callback regardless of the response success.

```
$.when.apply($, promises).always(function () {
    setButtons(box, c)
});
```

Comment: i thought that done meant "when i finish, whether succeded or failed"